# ls linux command: how to filter files in other directories

Tags: linux, search, ls

I know what `ls folder/` and `ls *abc*` do in linux. I want to filter out some files in a specific folder.

I tried this: `ls folder/ *abc` but it does not return correct values.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using find.

`find folder/ -d 1 -name '*abc'`

`folder/`: Path to search

`-d 1`: Only search one level down. This prevents it from searching all subdirectories below the folder you're looking for. Remove this if you want that behavior.

`-name '*abc'`: The pattern to search for.

More information can be gotten with `man find`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier, `find` might be a better option, but to do what you want using `ls`, try filtering using `grep`:

```
user@host:/etc$ ls homeassistant | grep config
config
configuration.yaml
configuration_bak.yaml
dockerconfig
dockerconfig.bak
```

.. As this returns all files and folders containing the word "*config*" from the directory *homeassistant*.